# What's wrong with my wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, technical-issues

Today, I got the game *Just Dance 2* and after I inserted the disk into the Wii machine, it said it needed to be updated to the newest version of the OS. I pressed `Yes`.

Once it was done updating, I reinserted the disk into the Wii and the icon that shows the game is blank!

I didn't know what to do about it so I restarted the wii, hoping that it would work. It didn't work at all! I panicked and just turned it off for now.

Afterwards when I tried the game, it didn't even let me into the game. What should I do?

Comment: Need more info.  What *exactly* happens?  What did it say about updating?  What does it show when you turn it on?

Comment: Your will? Are you talking about the Wii?

Comment: does your wii have an internet connection? in some cases it would require one for the update to be able to apply. Do other games still work fine?

Comment: ...did you mod your Wii?

Comment: What about other games? Do they also not work?

Comment: Try a different game and see if that works. At least then you'll know whether it's the Wii or the game.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things you can do to narrow down the culprit:

- **Try loading another game.**  If the problem happens with other games, your Wii is probably broken.
- If the Wii loads other games, **return your disc to the store where you bought and and get a new copy**.  Most places will replace opened games if they are defective.  If the new disc won't work, your Wii will probably need to get repaired.

If you determine your Wii isn't working, [you can send it to Nintendo to be repaired](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/repair/repair_form_us.jsp).  If it is out of warranty, they'll charge you a flat $100, which includes shipping.  If you do need to send it to Nintendo, **back up all your game data to an SD card first**.  Your console will most likely come back with all the game data erased (mine did).